# DataGridView Not Populating

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I've worked with web applications and GridViews, but I am working with a DataGridView for the first time now. I thought it would be pretty much the same thing, but I am having a little trouble trying to get it to fill correctly.

Here is what I currently have:

```
    familiesBindingSource.DataSource = FamilyLogic.GetFamiliesForView();
    FamiliesGridView.DataSource = familiesBindingSource;
```

The GetFamiliesView() method returns a DataTable. When I open up this form, nothing happens.

EDIT -- added more code..

```
    DataTable ds = FamilyLogic.GetFamiliesForView();
    familiesBindingSource.DataSource = ds;

    FamiliesGridView.DataSource = familiesBindingSource;
```

I could also post the GetFamiliesForView() method, but I am 100% sure it's not in there. It's returning the correct info and the DataSource field of the FamiliesGridView does contain the correct information when I step through it.

Comment: I took your suggestion and did this. The method is in fact returning the correct data.

Comment: Could you post how you have `FamiliesGridView` set up? May help provide a clue.

Comment: All I did was drag a DataGridView control from the toolbox on to a form to get it.

Comment: I added more code to the original post. I did check the DataSource of my GridView and it did have the correct information in it, which is really strange. I tried the Invalidate() method, but that didn't help either. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I found the issue. I did not realize that I needed these two lines of code.

```
    FamiliesGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    FamiliesGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Thanks for the help, all.